# How to find sum of a column in data table flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to find the sum of all data cells of the column if the data cells are double values?

```
DataTable(
      columns: [
              DataColumn(label: Text("Revenue(M)"),
            rows: snapshot.data.map((e) => DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(Text(e.expectedRevenue.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto Regular',
                      color: Colors.black
                  ),)), ]
            )).toList(),
          )
```

**I need to find the sum of all data cells of the column Revenue(M)**

Comment: Don't get it, can you provide bit more information or the context and I can try to help.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: I have updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done also inside your `map` method, but I added an example here to do it outside.
You can do this in multiple ways e.g. with `foreach`:

```
double revenueSum = 0;
snapshot.data.forEach((item) {
   revenueSum += item.expectedRevenue;
});
```

Bit cleaner way:

```
double revenueSum = snapshot.data.reduce((a, b) => a.expectedRevenue + b.expectedRevenue);
```

If you really want to do it inside the `map` method:

```
double revenueSum = 0;
DataTable(
  columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Text("Revenue(M)"),
        rows: snapshot.data.map((e) {
          revenueSum += e.expectedRevenue;
          return DataRow(
            cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text(e.expectedRevenue.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto Regular',
                    color: Colors.black
                  ),
                ),
             ],
        ).toList(),
     }
   ]
)
```

You might want to check before any of them if your item is actually `null` and then do something like using 0:

```
item?.expectedRevenue ?? 0
```